# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error because of loader interceptor in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 project. And I create an interceptor for showing 'loading' panel.But because of this loading panel, I'm taking this error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'` .How can I fix this?

**My interceptor**

```
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private ch: CommonHelper) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest < any >, next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
      this.ch.showLoader();
      return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
          tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              this.ch.hideLoader();
            }
          }, (error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              this.ch.messageHelper.showErrorMessage('Error Occured');
            }
            this.ch.hideLoader();
          })
        );
    }
}
```

**My show and hide methods**

```
showLoader() {
    this.globals.displayLoader = true;
  }

hideLoader() {
    this.globals.displayLoader = false;
  }
```

**My layout.html**

```
 <div class="loading-screen" *ngIf="ch.globals.displayLoader">
    <div class="loading-loader"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you add code where you have added `*ngIf`?

Comment: I edited my question and added my html and methods @PardeepJain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put your method to show/hide in setTimeout, like this -

```
setTimeout(() => {this.ch.hideLoader();}, 0)
```

For more explanation refer here -

- https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: Thanks this worked. But, it seem like a tricky way. Is it true? Can it be disadvantage of this method in future? Or is this method common way for achieve this? I dont understand how `settimeout` fix this issue. Because, we didn't wrote forexample `1000 ms`. We wrote zero. @PardeepJain

Comment: Not tricky way exactly, I honestly don't know about any disadvantage of this till now. Even I have used this so many times in code. I didn't wrote `1000ms` or `Xms` because my aim is just to call asynchronously.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again @PardeepJain

Comment: I had this same issue. Putting the loader in its own component helped me resolve it. i.e., instead of embedding the  loading div tags inside layout.html, created a loader component and put it in the layout.html (e.g., <loader></loader>. I believe this will take care of destroying and creating the loader between navigation helping you avoid using/setting timeouts.